# Algorithm in LaTeX doesn't show for or while loops

Tags: algorithms, loops

I have a LaTeX document for a report, it's a bit extense and I have to include a relatively large algorithm. I had issued with it because instead of displaying through the pages I wanted it went to the end of the document or above the bibliography. I managed to fix it by deleting the font size in the package `\documentclass{article}`, but, while are for loops don't appear as contidions in the execution of the document. I'll add the code with only the relevant information for this question. It's one of my first documents in LaTeX so I would appreciate patience and any advice.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{algorithm} 
\usepackage{algpseudocode} 
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{algcompatible}

\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
    \caption{\textbf{procedure} GRASP(MaxIterations,Seed)} 
    \begin{algorithmic}[1]
        \State $Set f* \leftarrow \infty;$
        \For {$k=1,...,MaxIterations \ldots$}
        
            \State $S \leftarrow GreedyRandomizedAlgoritm(Seed);$
            \Procedure{GreedyRandomizedAlgorithm}{$Seed$}
            \State $S \leftarrow 0$
            \State Initialize the candidate set: $C \leftarrow E;$
            \State Evaluate the incremental cost $c(e)$ for all $e \in C;$
            \While {$C \neq 0$}
                \State Build a list with the candidate elements having the smallest incremental costs;
                \State Select an element s from the restricted candidate list at random;
                \State Incorporate $s$ into the solition: $S \leftarrow S\cup\left \{  s\right \};$
                \State Update the candidate set $C;$
                \State Reevaluate the incremental cost $c(e) for all e \in C;$
            \EndWhile
            \State\textbf{return} $S;$
            \EndProcedure
            
            \If {$S$ is not feasible }
            \State $S \leftarrow RepairSolution(S);$
            \EndIf
            \State $S \leftarrow LocalSearch(S);$
            
            \Procedure{LocalSearch}{$S$}
            \While {$S$ is not locally optimal }
                \State Find $S' \in N(S)$ with $f(S') < f(S);$
                \State $S \leftarrow S';$
            \EndWhile
            \State\textbf{return} $S;$
            \EndProcedure
            
            \If {$f(S) < f* $}
            \State $S* \leftarrow S;$
            \State $f* \leftarrow f(S);$
            \EndIf
\EndFor
\State\textbf{return} $S*;$
    \end{algorithmic} 
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Removing `\usepackage{algcompatible}` shows the loops for your document.

Comment: That did the trick, thanks! I'll check the other thread too and see if it helps. Thank you for your patience.

Comment: Do you have any advice if I want the algorithm to respect its position? In the document it's printed at the end instead of the position I gave it. I don't know if this is because it's too long.

Comment: You can remove `\begin{algorithm}`, remove also the line with `\caption`, and remove `\end{algorithm}`, then it will be printed in place (and possibly overflow the page).

Comment: Thank you so much!